# Freebsd, ipfw sched - config type = QFQ get frozen

Tags: freebsd, traffic-shaping, ipfw

I have some freebsd soft-router

$uname -r

```
 8.2-STABLE
```

code for ipfw:

```
 pipe 50 config bw 70Mbit/s
 sched 50 config type QFQ
 queue 502 config sched 50 weight 1 mask dst-ip 0xffffffff
 queue 501 config sched 50 weight 9 mask dst-ip 0xffffffff

 add 01501 queue 502 ip from 10.32.0.0/14 to 10.32.0.0/14 out via vlan*
 add 01601 queue 501 ip from any to any out via ng*
```

1. vlans over device em1
2. ng created my mpd5

After rebooting i see the same each times, after 6-15 hours of work all traffic through vlan and ng frozen.

If i delete ipfw rules 1501 and 1601 , traffic start works immediately.

If i use WFQ2+ policy for scheduler all works ok.

So, its a QFQ bug? or some my fault in config?

Comment: Must be a bug in QFQ (it is very new). Trying to find a PR now, but haven't yet... Might want to [submit your own](http://www.freebsd.org/send-pr.html).